# Search for location after enabling it within the app

Tags: android, gps

So I found this code online to help with using GPS on android and right now I've got my app to find my current location if my GPS is on before running the application. But I was wondering how I would be able to find my location in the following situation:
1. Location is turned off.
2. Run the app.
3. Turn location on from the power toggles.

The code I'm using for GPS is:

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

// Get Class Name
private static String TAG = GPSTracker.class.getName();

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS Status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS Tracking is enabled
boolean isGPSTrackingEnabled = false;

Location location;
double latitude;
double longitude;

// How many Geocoder should return our GPSTracker
int geocoderMaxResults = 1;

// The minimum distance to change updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 ; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

// Store LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER or LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER information
private String provider_info;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

/**
 * Try to get my current location by GPS or Network Provider
 */
public void getLocation() {

    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        //getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        // Try to get location if you GPS Service is enabled
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            this.isGPSTrackingEnabled = true;

            Log.d(TAG, "Application use GPS Service");

            /*
             * This provider determines location using
             * satellites. Depending on conditions, this provider may take a while to return
             * a location fix.
             */

            provider_info = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

        } else if (isNetworkEnabled) { // Try to get location if you Network Service is enabled
            this.isGPSTrackingEnabled = true;

            Log.d(TAG, "Application use Network State to get GPS coordinates");

            /*
             * This provider determines location based on
             * availability of cell tower and WiFi access points. Results are retrieved
             * by means of a network lookup.
             */
            provider_info = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

        }

        // Application can use GPS or Network Provider
        if (!provider_info.isEmpty()) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    provider_info,
                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                    this
            );

            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider_info);
                updateGPSCoordinates();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
    }
}

/**
 * Update GPSTracker latitude and longitude
 */
public void updateGPSCoordinates() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
}

/**
 * GPSTracker latitude getter and setter
 * @return latitude
 */
public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    return latitude;
}

/**
 * GPSTracker longitude getter and setter
 * @return
 */
public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    return longitude;
}

/**
 * GPSTracker isGPSTrackingEnabled getter.
 * Check GPS/wifi is enabled
 */
public boolean getIsGPSTrackingEnabled() {

    return this.isGPSTrackingEnabled;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this method will stop using GPS in your app
 */
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 */
public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    //Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Disabled");

    //Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("To find the restaurants nearest to you, please turn on your GPS");

    //On Pressing Setting button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.action_settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    //On pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}

/**
 * Get list of address by latitude and longitude
 * @return null or List<Address>
 */
public List<Address> getGeocoderAddress(Context context) {
    if (location != null) {

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);

        try {
            /**
             * Geocoder.getFromLocation - Returns an array of Addresses
             * that are known to describe the area immediately surrounding the given latitude and longitude.
             */
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, this.geocoderMaxResults);

            return addresses;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Try to get AddressLine
 * @return null or addressLine
 */
public String getAddressLine(Context context) {
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0);

        return addressLine;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Try to get Locality
 * @return null or locality
 */
public String getLocality(Context context) {
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String locality = address.getLocality();

        return locality;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Try to get Postal Code
 * @return null or postalCode
 */
public String getPostalCode(Context context) {
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String postalCode = address.getPostalCode();

        return postalCode;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Try to get CountryName
 * @return null or postalCode
 */
public String getCountryName(Context context) {
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String countryName = address.getCountryName();

        return countryName;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Also in the OnCreate method, I've instantiated the class as follows:

```
gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this){
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out. For some reason, there was no network_provider and since gps_provider was off, it would get to the line

```
if (!provider_info.isEmpty()) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                provider_info,
                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                this
        );
```

and would just pass over it and not run the requestLocationUpdates, hence not allowing the gpsTracker object to be notified whether anything was being updated or not. All I did was I made

```
String provider_info = LocationManager.GPS_LOCATION;
```